# Css path changed after update wordpress to new version

Tags: updates

I have updated my wordpress site.After updating the layout of wp-admin side is changed when i inspect the error it shows

```
http://local.capitalsmartlatest.com/wp-content/plugins/C:/wamp64/www/capitalsmartlatest/wp-content/themes/ismart-careers/plugins/locations/lib/GP_MegaSeptember/assets/css/gp_mega_september.css?ver=5.3.2
```

it adding C:/wamp64 in the css url.I have try to find any solution but couldn't find any useful solution.I have tried 
`define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false ); 
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );`
but the problem is still there.Is there any other way?

Comment: `C:/wamp64` is a folder path, not a URL, you shouldn't be setting directory paths as URLs. Did you make any modifications to WordPress core files?

Comment: I didn't change any thing the path is created after the update now my question is how i can remove C:/wamp64 or fix the url.

Comment: Can you not go to the settings page in WP Admin and just change it there?

Comment: site url is correct and some of css files have correct path but in some url C:wamp64 is added .The site is working fine but when i open any page in wp-admin the some of css file failed to load because of url.

Comment: This is extremely unusual, do you have any caching or optimisation plugins present? Have you confirmed every constant in your wp-config.php is set correctly? Judging from the URL you showed me it's probably a poorly written theme causing the issue. Switch to one of the default themes to confirm if this is the case

Comment: Can you post the snippet where the styles and scripts are enqueued?

Comment: I am facing this issue on wp-admin site.when i try to open any page to edit.

Comment: I have find the issue that some plugins are include in function.php file 
require_once 'plugins/team-members/tmm.php';
require_once 'plugins/wp-customize-image-gallery-control-master/customize-image-gallery-control.php';
require_once 'plugins/wp-extra-file-types/wp-extra-file-types.php';
in this way.Now how i can fix it so plugin still include in function so the follow don't effect?

Comment: $css_url = plugins_url('assets/css/gp_mega_september.css', __FILE__);
   wp_register_style( 'gp_mega_september', $css_url);
   wp_enqueue_style( 'gp_mega_september' );